# Are there advantages to using the CUDA vector types?

Tags: cuda, abstract-data-type

CUDA provides built-in vector data types like `uint2`, `uint4` and so on. Are there any advantages to using these data types?

Let's assume that I have a tuple which consists of two values, A and B. One way to store them in memory is to allocate two arrays. The first array stores all the A values and the second array stores all the B values at indexes that correspond to the A values. Another way is to allocate one array of type `uint2`. Which one should I use? Which way is recommended? Does members of `uint3` i.e `x`, `y`, `z` reside side by side in memory?

Comment: It seems really strange that CUDA doesn't provide built in vector operations since every shading language does and you know the hardware underneath supports it. The only place I see the CUDA API using them is in the texture reads. This is the biggest mystery I have concerning CUDA.

Comment: @wcochran: *Every* operation in CUDA is a vector operation: each of the 32 threads in the warp corresponds to one slot in the vector. There's just enough hardware/software support to present it to you in a multithreading model.

Comment: Where is dot, cross, add, sub, scale, reflect, etc...?

Answer (score 7):

This is going to be a bit speculative but may add to @ArchaeaSoftware's answer.

I'm mainly familiar with Compute Capability 2.0 (Fermi). For this architecture, I don't think that there is any performance advantage to using the vectorized types, except maybe for 8- and 16-bit types.

Looking at the declaration for char4:

```
struct __device_builtin__ __align__(4) char4
{
    signed char x, y, z, w;
};
```

The type is aligned to 4 bytes. I don't know what `__device_builtin__` does. Maybe it triggers some magic in the compiler...

Things look a bit strange for the declarations of `float1`, `float2`, `float3` and `float4`:

```
struct __device_builtin__ float1
{
    float x;
};

__cuda_builtin_vector_align8(float2, float x; float y;);

struct __device_builtin__ float3
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct __device_builtin__ __builtin_align__(16) float4
{
    float x, y, z, w;
};
```

`float2` gets some form of special treatment. `float3` is a struct without any alignment and `float4` gets aligned to 16 bytes. I'm not sure what to make of that.

Global memory transactions are 128 bytes, aligned to 128 bytes. Transactions are always performed for a full warp at a time. When a warp reaches a function that performs a memory transaction, say a 32-bit load from global memory, the chip will at that time perform as many transactions as are necessary for servicing all the 32 threads in the warp. So, if all the accessed 32-bit values are within a single 128-byte line, only one transaction is necessary. If the values come from different 128-byte lines, multiple 128-byte transactions are performed. For each transaction, the warp is put on hold for around 600 cycles while the data is fetched from memory (unless it's in the L1 or L2 caches).

So, I think the key to finding out what type of approach gives the best performance, is to consider which approach causes the fewest 128-byte memory transactions.

Assuming that the built in vector types are just structs, some of which have special alignment, using the vector types causes the values to be stored in an interleaved way in memory (array of structs). So, if the warp is loading all the `x` values at that point, the other values (`y`, `z`, `w`) will be pulled in to L1 because of the 128-byte transactions. When the warp later tries to access those, it's possible that they are no longer in L1, and so, new global memory transactions must be issued. Also, if the compiler is able to issue wider instructions to read more values in at the same time, for future use, it will be using registers for storing those between the point of the load and the point of use, perhaps increasing the register usage of the kernel.

On the other hand, if the values are packed into a struct of arrays, the load can be serviced with as few transactions as possible. So, when reading from the `x` array, only `x` values are loaded in the 128-byte transactions. This could cause fewer transactions, less reliance on the caches and a more even distribution between compute and memory operations.

Comment: "So, I think the key to finding out what type of approach gives the best performance, is to consider which approach causes the fewest 128-byte memory transactions." Not necessarily. You should watch one of Paulius' presentations, e.g. http://bit.ly/OzutxO. Increasing the transactions in flight often helps improve bandwidth utilization.

Comment: "So, if the warp is loading all the x values at that point, the other values (y, z, w) will be pulled in to L1 because of the 128-byte transactions. When the warp later tries to access those, it's possible that they are no longer in L1". If you load from a float4 array into a float4 variable (which will be stored in registers), you don't have to worry about whether or not y, z, and w will be in cache when the thread goes to use them, because the thread will have them in registers. For apps that need float4 data (or that fit one of the other structs), generally YES, you should use the structs.

Comment: @harrism What does exactly `__builtin_align__(16)` in case of above struct for float4?

Comment: It tells the compiler to allocate the struct (or array of such structs) on a 16-byte aligned boundary. I believe `__builtin_align__` is a wrapper around `__align__`. You can confirm by digging through the CUDA headers. `__align__` should be described in the CUDA C programming guide.

Comment: @harrism: Thank you for the pointer to the presentations. I was at the GTC but don't think I caught any of Paulius' presentations. I'll try to get to them. Don't know what I was thinking, about having to depend on the caches after having loaded a vector type... I'd delete my answer, but then your comments would be lost as well. Want to add an answer with those?

Comment: Nah, I think between your answer and Nick's, and the comments, it is covered well.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe the built-in tuples in CUDA ([u]int[2|4], float[2|4], double[2]) have any intrinsic advantages; they exist mostly for convenience.  You could define your own C++ classes with the same layout and the compiler would operate on them efficiently.  The hardware does have native 64-bit and 128-bit loads, so you'd want to check the generated microcode to know for sure.

As for whether you should use an array of uint2 (array of structures or AoS) or two arrays of uint (structure of arrays or SoA), there are no easy answers - it depends on the application.  For built-in types of convenient size (2x32-bit or 4x32-bit), AoS has the advantage that you only need one pointer to load/store each data element. SoA requires multiple base pointers, or at least multiple offsets and separate load/sore operations per element; but it may be faster for workloads that sometimes only operate on a subset of the elements.

As an example of a workload that uses AoS to good effect, look at the nbody sample (which uses float4 to hold XYZ+mass of each particle).  The Black-Scholes sample uses SoA, presumably because float3 is an inconvenient element size.

Comment: The hardware has 64- and 128-bit loads *and stores*. Generally structures *like* `uint2` and `uint4`, *if* they make sense for your data and algorithm, are advantageous because they can increase the per-thread transaction size and therefore more efficiently use the available bandwidth. You can make your own custom structs, but ensure that they specify alignment like the CUDA-provided structs do.

Comment: @harrism So if I'm not wrong this goes like this...All members of uint2 will reside side-by-side in memory hence using an array of type uint2 CAN lead to less memory transactions because one uncovers two values..

Comment: Yeah.  See how float4 is used in the nbody, particles and other physics demos in the CUDA SDK.

Comment: +1 I know this is an old post but I think your second and third paragraph are really important. Often in parallel computing I usually hear that SoA is better, but that is not always the case as evidenced by the nbody sample code.

Answer (score 3):

There's some good info [in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676806/efficiency-of-cuda-vector-types-float2-float3-float4) that contradicts much of the major conclusions said here.